# How to conditionally set input attribute as disabled (Adobe Sightly HTL)

Tags: sightly

Considering that the inputs can have disabled attributes, how one would set it up depending if the condition is true? :-)

Concept:
`<input ${condition ? disabled : ''} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since falsy attributes are removed in HTL/Sightly, you can write:

```
<input disabled="${condition}" />
```

See also https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#2231-detailed-examples

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this was posted but in case somebody still needs the answer is by using a model boolean variable (data-sly-use.model) and data-sly-attribute.disabled

It would be:

```
 <input data-sly-attribute.disabled="${model.isDisabled}"/>
```

Or simply:

```
<input data-sly-attribute.disabled="${true}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do that with vuejs.

It would be :

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    disabled: 0,
  },
});
```

```
<input :disabled="disabled == 1" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Disco, but I am looking for the solution in the context Adobe HTL, rather then VueJS :-)